# Sum of Random Variables formalism vs intuiton

Tags: probability, random-variables

Say for example $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Random variable where $\Omega := \lbrace \text{``Members of a population''} \rbrace $ and $X$ is a map to their heights. To my question: Suppose we have $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ independent identically distributed (i.i.d) copies of $X$. What is their sum $S_n:=X_1 + \ldots + X_n$ formally supossed to represent ? I am asking this because of the following: Pick someon of the population $\Omega$ called $\omega$. Assume $\omega$ is 180 cm tall. Then formally the sum gives me $S_n(\omega) = X_1(\omega) + \ldots + X_n(\omega) = n\cdot 180$ cm. But I know intuitively the sum of these n random variables is supposed to represent a random sample of n heights of a population: $S_n(\omega) = 190 cm + 172 cm + \ldots + 187 cm$. So formalism and intuition contradict themselves. Whats wrong maybe my definition of $S_n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the probability space in your first case with one sample is different from the case with multiple samples.

Basically what you're asking is:

> Suppose $X$ is a random variable living in a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. How do we formalise the notion of $n$ i.i.d. samples of $X$, or the sum of $n$ i.i.d. samples of $X$?

Here's a set-up that works. We will call our new probability space $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}',\mathbb{P}')$, which is just the product of $n$ copies of the original space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. In particular, the sample space is $\Omega' := \Omega^n$, i.e. $\Omega$-valued strings of length-$n$.

Now our $X_1,\dots, X_n$ will be measurable maps living in this new probability space. For $i = 1,\dots n$ and $\omega = (\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n) \in \Omega'$, we define $X_i(\omega) := X(\omega_i)$. Then $S_n := X_1 + \dots X_n$ is also defined on this probability space and is equal to $S_n(\omega) = S_n(\omega_1,\dots \omega_n) = X(\omega_1) + \dots X(\omega_n)$.

So in your case, $\omega \in \Omega'$ represents picking $n$ people from the population at a time (with repetition) and then each $X_i$ asks the height of $\omega_i$, the $i$-th person.